why start jar using systemd cant visit mysql,the error writes having no privileges
why start jar using systemd cant visit mysql,the error writes having no privileges.I test it in VMware.the user to run jar whatever is root or normal user cant visit due to the problem of privileges.But i systemctl stop my app.service then start it ,it has the privileges.Why?I hope systemd to do this thing and the jar have the privileges automatically.And this is my setting,the Selunix is disabled.
[Unit]
Description=My Java Application  
Requires=mysql.service  
After=mysql.service

[Service]
User=yumia
WorkingDirectory=/home/yumia/myapp
Environment="IP=127.0.0.1"
Environment="DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/healthsys?user=user1&password=1234"
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'while ! /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -h localhost -u root -p1234 -e "SELECT 1"; do sleep 1; done'
ExecStart=/usr/local/jdk/bin/java Dspring.application.json='{"ip":"${IP}"}' -jar /home/yumia/myapp/MySQLShiYan-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target



11月 21 19:39:44 kylin123 java[3740]: 2024-11-21T19:39:44.559+08:00  WARN 3740 --- [healthsys] [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestNotUsableException: ServletOutputStream failed to flush: java.io.IOException: 权限不够]

I set mysql service and jar service automatically start.But after i restart my vmware i check through journalclt -u app.service -f,it says have no privileges,but i systemctl stop and then start it,it works smoothly.

Please show us the actual error(s).  Is the Operating System complaining about privileges, or MySQL?
Your ExecStartPre command looks like it's /waiting/ for the mysqld service to [fully] start.  I suspect there are better ways of doing this.
Also, look at the ways you can avoid putting passwords on the mysql command-line.

At first, I thought that the execution order of MySQL and the JAR program was causing the JAR program to not have enough permissions. So I added a wait in ExecStartPre to ensure that MySQL is fully started before executing. However, after adding it, I still encountered permission issues after restarting the virtual machine.

But when I input systemctl stop for the jar program in the terminal and then start it again, the jar program has permissions, and I can retrieve data from the MySQL database.Is this a permission issue, or could it be something else?
